# Detecting Keypresses in the Turtle module in Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want it so my Up key moves the turtle and my S key cleans the screen. Also, the up key command works:

```
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()

jack = Turtle("turtle")
jack.color("red", "green")
jack.pensize(10)
jack.speed(0)

def clean(x,y):
    jack.clear()
def move():
    jack.forward(100)

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(clean,"S")
turtle.onkey(move,"Up")

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: By passing `"S"` to the `onkey()` method, you are specifically requiring an uppercase letter to be typed.  Try `"s"` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jasonharper is correct about the capitalization issue (+1) but you clearly have other issues with this code as you import turtle two different ways.  I.e. you're mixing turtle's *object-oriented* API with its *functional* API.  Let's rewrite the code to just use the object-oriented API:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def move():
    turtle.forward(100)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle('turtle')
turtle.color('red', 'green')
turtle.pensize(10)
turtle.speed('fastest')

screen.onkey(turtle.clear, 's')
screen.onkey(move, 'Up')
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

I've changed variable names to make it clear which methods are *screen* instance methods and which are *turtle* instance methods.  Your double import obscured this.